# IOS app development on Xcode (12 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

i'm following a tutorial for a login app with firebase and i have only one error i can't understand. I already searched online and i found somenthing similar here on stackoverflow but didn't understand the solution (it was too old).
This is the error:[image]

Can you guys help me with that?

Comment: Looks like something's wrong in the framework

Comment: yes but what can be?

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you are compiling duplicate source files.

1. Open `PromisesObjC` in the Project Navigator
2. Go to the **Build Phases** tab
3. Check the **Compile Sources** section for duplicates and remove the duplicate entry
4. Clean Build Folder

Comment: Sorry, how can i access build phases tab?

Comment: If you are using CocoaPods, click on the Pods Project, then select the PromisesObjC target. Now you should see the Build Phases tab.

Comment: No wai my bad, i selected the main project and not the pods :D

Comment: Sorry, do i need to delete the list?

Comment: Only if there are duplicates. I can see e.g. FBLPromise.o and FBLPromise 2.o in your screenshot. In this case you should only delete FBLPromise 2.o

Comment: There were 2 FBLPromise.h and .m, i deleted the duplicates, do i have to eliminate FBLPromise 2.h if i already have FBLPromise.h?

Comment: Exactly, you have to remove all entries with the " 2" at the end. The should be only one entry for every file.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when you install Firebase via Swift Package Manager, and Google AdMobs SDK via CocoaPods. Unfortunately, this is how the current official documentation guides you. You end up with duplicated libraries in your project.

After trying many things, I've got rid of this issue by installing Firebase via Cocoapods as well.